# Flutter Tab bar can't take all space

Tags: flutter, tabs, stack, space, tabbar

I want to make a custom tab widget and set a list of this widgets to a tab bar. But tab bar can't take all space and some space will remain. I try to wrap it with PreferredSize but it doesn't work .
The tab bar (ScrollTabBar) :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  blurRadius: 5.0,
                  offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75),
                ),
              ],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.borderRadiusT),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            height: widget.tabHeight,
            child: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(widget.tabHeight),
              child: TabBar(
                indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: widget.indicatorColor,
                    width: widget.indicatorWheight,
                  ),
                  insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: widget.horizontalPadding,
                  ),
                ),
                indicatorWeight: widget.indicatorWheight,
                indicatorColor: widget.indicatorColor,
                labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: 0,
                  right: widget.horizontalPadding,
                  left: widget.horizontalPadding,
                ),
                labelColor: widget.activeTextColor,
                unselectedLabelColor: widget.diactiveTextColor,
                controller: widget.tabController,
                tabs: widget.tabList,
                isScrollable: true,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: widget.tabController,
              children: [
                for (var builder in widget.screenList) builder.call(context)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

tabList is list of FTabComp :

```
FTabComp(
  String title,
  Key key,
  ScrollTabBar parent, {
  bool haveDivider = true,
}) {
  return Tab(
    key: key,
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      width: parent.tabLength,
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(title),
          ),
          haveDivider
              ? Positioned.fill(
                  left: parent.tabLength * - 1.5,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: double.maxFinite,
                    child: VerticalDivider(
                      color: parent.outerBackgroundColor,
                      thickness: parent.dviderWidth,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Center()
          ,
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Container are red . Tabs are blue , if you solve this , I will say thank you.
 [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5zcS.png)

Comment: Maybe it is because of padding.

Comment: in label padding "
                  right: widget.horizontalPadding,
                  left: widget.horizontalPadding,"

are zero?

Comment: I don't think horizontal padding make this, But after deleting all padding , result is the same.  @hossein-asadi

Comment: try removing both label 'padding' and 'insets'.

Comment: I try , but it doesn't help. @ravipatel0508

Comment: @BehzadShabanifard But I copied and executed your code, after removing the padding, the problem was fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the [TabBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) use the maximum width of the screen you should remove the [isScrollable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar/isScrollable.html) property or set it to `false`. This way the `TabBar` is going to fill the entire width of the screen and resize each tab accordingly. [From the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar/isScrollable.html), *each tab gets an equal share of the available space).* Also, the `tabLength` should be removed as it doesn't make sense anymore.

Now, the position of [VerticalDivider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/VerticalDivider-class.html) should be calculated. It should take into account the screen width, the width of the tab, and also the padding between tabs. And it should be places in a `Stack` with the `TabBar` to make it the same height as the `TabBar` itself.

The algorithm to calculate the tab width can be something like this:

```dart
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double tabLength = (width -
            horizontalPadding * (tabCount + 1) -
            horizontalPadding * (tabCount - 1)) /
        tabCount;
```

Below are the screenshots of the final result. Take a look also on the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=a8ac930d6bbb59e76d6a74ad5027f98a) (Wait a little to run):

| Small | Medium | Large |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

Take a look at the changed code below:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;
  late TabController tabController2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    tabController2 = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double horizontalPadding = 8;

    return Scaffold(
      body: ScrollTabBar(
        tabController: tabController,
        horizontalPadding: horizontalPadding,
        tabList: const [
          FTabComp(
            title: 'secKey',
            key: ValueKey('tab1'),
          ),
          FTabComp(
            title: 'firstKey',
            key: ValueKey('tab2'),
          ),
          FTabComp(
            title: 'otherKey',
            key: ValueKey('tab3'),
          ),
          FTabComp(
            title: 'anotherKey',
            key: ValueKey('tab4'),
          ),
        ],
        screenList: [
          (context) => const Text('Tab 1'),
          (context) => const Text('Tab 2'),
          (context) => const Text('Tab 3'),
          (context) => const Text('Tab 4'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollTabBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final double borderRadiusT;
  final double tabHeight;
  final Color indicatorColor;
  final Color activeTextColor;
  final Color diactiveTextColor;
  final double indicatorWheight;
  final double horizontalPadding;
  final Color outerBackgroundColor;
  final double dviderWidth;
  final TabController? tabController;
  final List<Widget> tabList;
  final List<Widget Function(BuildContext)> screenList;
  final bool haveDivider;
  const ScrollTabBar({
    Key? key,
    this.borderRadiusT = 4,
    this.tabHeight = 48,
    this.indicatorColor = Colors.blue,
    this.activeTextColor = Colors.black,
    this.diactiveTextColor = Colors.white38,
    this.indicatorWheight = 8,
    this.horizontalPadding = 8,
    required this.tabController,
    required this.tabList,
    required this.screenList,
    this.outerBackgroundColor = Colors.black,
    this.dviderWidth = 4,
    this.haveDivider = true,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScrollTabBar> createState() => _ScrollTabBarState();
}

class _ScrollTabBarState extends State<ScrollTabBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double tabLength = (width -
            widget.horizontalPadding * (widget.tabList.length + 1) -
            widget.horizontalPadding * (widget.tabList.length - 1)) /
        widget.tabList.length;

    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  blurRadius: 5.0,
                  offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75),
                ),
              ],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.borderRadiusT),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            height: widget.tabHeight,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                TabBar(
                  indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: widget.indicatorColor,
                      width: widget.indicatorWheight,
                    ),
                    insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: widget.horizontalPadding,
                    ),
                  ),
                  indicatorWeight: widget.indicatorWheight,
                  indicatorColor: widget.indicatorColor,
                  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: widget.horizontalPadding,
                    left: widget.horizontalPadding,
                  ),
                  labelColor: widget.activeTextColor,
                  unselectedLabelColor: widget.diactiveTextColor,
                  controller: widget.tabController,
                  tabs: widget.tabList,
                ),
                for (int i = 1; i < widget.tabList.length; i++)
                  Positioned.fill(
                    left: (widget.horizontalPadding + tabLength + widget.horizontalPadding) * i - (widget.dviderWidth / 2),
                    right: width,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: widget.tabHeight,
                      child: VerticalDivider(
                        color: widget.outerBackgroundColor,
                        thickness: widget.dviderWidth,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: widget.tabController,
              children: [
                for (var builder in widget.screenList) builder.call(context)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FTabComp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const FTabComp({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Tab(
      key: key,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(title),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I want divider be like [this](https://imgur.com/HBx18hu) . @lepsch

Comment: Please take a look at the updated answer. Check the screenshots and the new link to the live demo.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Stack, you use `Positioned.fill`. try removing it

Comment: Any solution so I can keep it ? The stack make problem or Positioned.fill ?

Comment: Positioned.fill might cause it.

Comment: I need it because of vertical divider , you can see it in the image . If I remove Positioned.fill, Is there any alternative way to have vertical divider ?

Comment: You can use VerticalDivider Widget.